# When I update a record in MERN stack it deletes the object

Tags: reactjs, express, routes, request

When I try to update a record, it deletes the objects instead of updating them. I know my routes are correct since it's working in Postman.

Routes:

```
router.route('/update/:id').post(function (req, res) {
Bet.findById({ _id: req.params.id }, function (err, bets) {
    if (!bets)
        res.status(404).send("Data not found.");
    else {
        bets.result = req.body.result;
        bets.profit = req.body.profit;

        bets.save().then(bets => {
            res.json('Update complete.');
        })
            .catch(err => {
                res.status(400).send("Unable to update.");
            });
    }
});
});
```

App.js

```
handleSelection = async (value, id, event, key) => {
    const obj = {
        result: "Win",
        profit: profits,
    }

    axios.post("http://localhost:5000/bet/update/" + key.id, obj)
            .then(res => console.log(res.data));

}
```

Example of a json;

```
{
   "_id": "5ddfe84f07a48861b4c0c153",
   "name": "asd",
   "profit": "-10",
   "result": "Loss"
}
```

When my code runs, it becomes like this:

```
{
   "_id": "5ddfe84f07a48861b4c0c153",
   "name": "asd"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is not deleting your document, but overwriting existing fields with empty values. And the reason is most probably that you don't send result and profit values in POST request body.

So I advise you to console.log req.body inside your route to see if result and values are there:

By the way you can shorten your code using findByIdAndUpdate method like this:

```
router.route('/update/:id').post(async (req, res) => {
  console.log("req.body: ", req.body);

  try {
    const { result, profit } = req.body;

    const response = await Bet.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {result,profit}, { new: true });

    if (!response) return res.status(400).send("Data not found");

    res.json("Update complete");
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
  }
})
```

To send a POST request, you can use postman, with this body:

[image: Postman screenshot]

And in your node console.log will log this:
[image: Node console]

After you see it works with postman, you can add the content-type headers to axios.post and try if it works. Also be sure the `console.log("obj: ", obj)` logs your object with the data you want.

```
console.log("obj: ", obj);
axios.post("http://localhost:5000/bet/update/" + key.id, obj,  
   {
    headers: { "content-type": "application/json" }
   })
```

Comment: How do I console log req.body? putting console.log(req.body); gives me no output

Comment: It means you are not posting req.body correctly. Can you try to post with postman?

Comment: @LukeRemming I added console.log to my answer, using this code can you send a post request to this route with postman and check what  is being logged in node app console?

Comment: returns req.body: {}, so its empty. how would I pass result and profit to express then? do they have to be in this.state?

Comment: @LukeRemming I updated the answer to send a POST request with postman. Please first test with postman, and if it works, it means the problem is in react side.

Comment: Yes it works with postman, so express isn't retrieving my result and profit field from react?

Comment: @LukeRemming I updated the answer, by adding a fix in react side, can you check and try?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203279/discussion-between-suleymansah-and-luke-remming).